# How does a wrapper class wrap the value of a datatype around its objects?

Tags: java

I needed a way to assign a String value to an object of a class I created, for a personal project. As expected,

```
String str = "Sample";
MyClass obj = (MyClass) str;
```

does not work, since `String` can't be converted to `MyClass` type. But then, how do wrapper classes take `String` inputs and convert them to, say, an `Integer` or a `Double` object? I have searched for "How do wrapper classes work?" but haven't found any solution to my question. All pages only give details of implementations of wrapper classes.

I wonder if you could hep me out. The ability to wrap `String` values around objects of `MyClass` as well as to unwrap them would greatly improve the aesthetics of my project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do wrapper classes take String inputs and convert them to, say, an Integer or a Double object?

They don't.  You generally have to use methods like `Integer.parseInt` or `Integer.valueOf` to convert between `String`s and `Integer`s, and other wrapper classes.

If you're asking how the *compiler* parses those literals, that uses e.g. `Integer.decode`, but that is something used *only* for primitive literals and *cannot* be made to work for your custom classes.  (It's not even available for other Java types that could productively use their own literal format, such as `BigInteger`.)

Comment: Say, I write BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("123456"). What happens in this case? Is the String value "123456" stored in b1, or something else?

Comment: There is a `String` literal which is passed at runtime to the perfectly normal `BigInteger` constructor which parses the `String`.

Comment: Oh, okay! That's some valuable info! Thanks. :-)